# Cast Optional<Any> to NSString in Swift

Tags: swift, signalr

I’m working on a small swift application to process some data coming in from a signalR server. I’m using the SignalR-ObjC client to receive the data, and I’ve got an event handler setup to get the data coming in.

```
hubConnection.received = { data in
   print(data!);
}
```

This is what the above line prints to the console:

```
{
   A = (2);
   H = SystemHub;
   M = ConnectedUserCount;
}
```

`print(type(of: data));` shows the type as **Optional< Any >**.
[And this is a frame of data received in debug mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LNv6R.png)

I am trying to get it into a String to parse it, hoping someone could give me a pointer on how I can cast/unwrap this? I thought the data incoming was an NSDictionary, but I can't seem to unwrap in anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a way, the `id` type in Objective-C now maps to the `Any` type in Swift, which describes a value of any type, whether a class, enum, struct, or any other Swift type. Here, `Any` is the type given to a collection when objects are heterogeneous.

You can clearly see your data is a dictionary and you can do as following to access it:

```
    hubConnection.received = { data in
        if let dict = data as? [String: Any] { // again any as value can be array or string
            print(dict)
        }
    }
```

You can access internal value objects as well.

```
        if let dict = data as? [String: Any], 
           let valueA = dict["A"] as? [Any], 
           let valueB = dict["B"] as? String, 
           let valueC = dict["C"] as? String {
            print(valueA)
            print(valueB)
            print(valueC)
        }
```

`as?` ensure that your object conforms to a particular data type or either it will return nil. So writing `data as? [String: Any]` is checking if data is a dictionary of `String` keys and `Any` values and we use `Any` as it can be either `Array`, `String`, `Number` or any other data type we are not sure about at this point.

Comment: Thanks @Ankit Jayaswal - that is a wonderfully clear explanation and has given me good context to not just solve but also understand the problem.